# Shell script with comment, command not found when creating variable

Tags: shell

I have the following script which works:

```
x=10
echo $x
now=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
echo $now
```

However, when I add a comment line at the beginning:

```
# comment
x=10
echo $x
now=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
echo $now
```

I get the following:

```
x=10: command not found
x: undefined variable
```

Why is the addition of the comment causing the script to fail?

if I do the following it works:

```
x=10
echo $x
now=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
# comment here
echo $now
```

Comment: Does that script have a `#!` shebang as its first line, or is just the bare commands?

Comment: Did you maybe wind up with DOS-style line endings in the file?

Comment: Don't know. I am using `vi` to write the script

Comment: The #! did not seem to change anything

Comment: `xxd «script»` or `od -a «script»` will let you look for funny characters. Also, is the code you're posting the exact code that's failing? Is the comment really `# comment`, or is it something else?

Comment: really `# comment` in this play script

Comment: @JohnB: Please post the output of xxd or od -a if possible. Also, what environment (OS, OS version version, shell, shell version)?

Comment: Can't cut and paste from there (other machine). Gnome 2.16.0. Not sure how to get shell/ shell version. The file is `myshell.sh` and I am running it by `./myshell.sh`

Comment: Try this: `bash myshell.sh`. That will run it with bash, so we can see if its some shell oddity. `sh --version` may provide the version. Also, OS and OS version. `uname -a` may help. But knowing e.g., distro would be nice too.

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1). When I run `bash myscript.bash` it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quirk of csh.  (Stop using csh!)  csh will process a script that does not begin with a '#' using a "standard shell" (quoting from the csh manpage.)  When the script begins with '#', csh parses it. Your script is not valid csh.

You should probably add a shebang line to avoid this type of issue.  That is, make the first line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: what is csh and how to I stop using it?

Comment: @JohnB: You can change your shell by running `chsh`. What is csh? csh is evil. `man csh` may give a less biased description.

Comment: csh is a shell.  (It is the program that interprets what you type at the command line.)  To use a different shell, just invoke it; type 'bash' for example.  Your script is interpreted by a shell, and from the syntax of your script it appears that you expect it to be interpreted by a bourne shell.  Make that explicit by adding the shebang line.  There are 2 main types of shell: bourne shells and c-shells.  The syntaxes are not compatible.

Comment: Use whatever you like as your interactive shell.  `sh` or `bash` is better than `cah` or `tcsh` *for scripts*, but tcsh in particular has some nice interactive features.  As long as you have a proper shebang (`#!`) at the top of your scripts you don't need to use the same shell for scripting and for interactive use.  Of course there's something to be said for consistency, but it's up to you.  The `!#` is the solution to your problem; `chsh` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
#
x=10
echo $x
now=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
echo $now
```

This works on my system (Ubuntu 11.04, 64bit). If that doesn't work then you may have some hidden special character in your file.

Comment: I didn't have the `#!/bin/sh`